# How to get multiple checkbox for one property in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am making a simple mvc project for my practice. But I don't know how to place multiple checkboxes for one property of model.

For example,

```
 public class TestVeiwModel
 {
     public string LanguagePreference {get; set;}
 }
```

In view, I would like to place 3 check boxes for this LanguagePreference property.
English, French and Other,
So user may choose only one of these check boxes or not choose any of these. 
If English is selected, LanguagePreference will be English. This behaves pretty much like radio button except it is possible to deselect. But I want this look like checkbox.

I tried to use @Html.CheckBoxFor and @Html.CheckBox helpers but I couldn't get this work.

I would really appreciate it if anyone can help me out.

Comment: Checkboxes make no sense in this case - a user can select all 3 (use radio buttons with a 'None' button)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use radio button.But if you need this kind of behavior of checkbox so, you can do with jquery.
You need one more property to get which one is selected.

```
public class TestVeiwModel
{
     public string LanguageName {get; set;}
     public bool IsSelected {get; set;}
}
```

After that bind you subject list and pass to view like that.

```
@model List<yourproejctName.modelNameSpace.TestVeiwModel> //Path of your model

for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(r => Model[i].IsSelected, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "chkBoxClass", onchange = "fun_Onchange(this)" })

   @Html.DisplayFor(r => Model.LanguageName)
}
```

And need to write jquery function :-

```
  function  fun_Onchange(evt)
  {
       if($(evt).is(':checked')){
        $('.chkBoxClass').prop('checked', false);
        $(evt).prop('checked', true);
    }
    else{
        $('.chkBoxClass').prop('checked', false);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write an enum for options like

```
    public enum LanguageOptionSelected
    {       
       English= 0,
       French= 1,        
       Other= 2
    }
```

And write below code in model:

```
public LanguageOptionSelected? Option { get; set; }
```